# Is “summer is back again” a figurative statement?

Tags: figurative

> The season is changing, but then summer is back again. Several days
> might pass, and then we experience that sharpness again, notice the
> few scattering ...

Is “summer is back again” a figurative statement?

The reason I doubt is that time cannot return. I think “summer comes” is appropriate.

Comment: Figurative for 'Summer _weather_ is back again', I suppose.

Comment: Speaking of seasons, I see *summer* as literal, not figurative. However, the entire sentence might be used as a metaphor if one isn't speaking about the weather.

Comment: Back doesn't necessarily imply motion; it can mean [returned to a former state](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back). But there's often not a clear delineation between literal and figurative.

Comment: Much of the language used with time is metaphorical.